# xsd validation code problems

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to get the XML file to validate clearly I have some problems with my car file cane any one point me in the right direction on what I need to change?

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<employees> xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="employees.xsd">

<emp> <first>Bill</first> <last>Johnson</last> </emp> <emp> <first>April</first> <last>Jones</last> </emp> <emp> <first>Chad</first> <last>Becker</last> </emp> <emp> <first>David</first> <last>Jones</last> </emp> </employees>
```

xsd code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="employees"> <xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>

<xs:element name="emp"> <xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <xs:pattern value="first|last" /> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>

<xs:element name="first">
```

Answer (score 0):

The XSD and XML code that you posted both have formatting problems. I'm not sure if they are problems with copying/pasting your code into SO, or problems with the code you're writing. I've taken the snippets you posted and created a schema and matching xml file that are both valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com">
<xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="employees">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="emp" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="emp">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="first"/>
            <xs:element ref="last"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

...and the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employees xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com">
<emp>
    <first>Bill</first>
    <last>Johnson</last>
</emp>
<emp>
    <first>April</first>
    <last>Jones</last>
</emp>
<emp>
    <first>Chad</first>
    <last>Becker</last>
</emp>
<emp>
    <first>David</first>
    <last>Jones</last>
</emp>
</employees>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help I have one other problem.  I get the below error when trying to validate. Validating "employees.xml" against "Internal DocType Declaration" 
Ln 3 Col 2 - The value of attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "employees" must not contain the '<' character.
1 Error

Comment: @Jon - At the end of the XML file I posted - there was a missing quote mark at the end of the `<employees>` tag. I fixed this in an edit.